# Reading mutiple directories using HIVE external table

Tags: hive

I have a directory in HDFS (say /user/hduser/table1) and under that directory there are multiple directories for different timestamps like `/user/hduser/table1/20160912000000` , `/user/hduser/table1/20160912100000` and `/user/hduser/table1/20160912121000`

How can I read all the files which are under those three directories through one HIVE external table. Means what do I have to specify in HIVE table's LOCATION parameter.

Answer (score 1):

I am able to read nested folders with the below settings.

```
set hive.mapred.supports.subdirectories=true;
set mapred.input.dir.recursive=true;
```

I did set it while creating the table and then able to select data from the table. Location keyword I mentioned as below

```
LOCATION '/user/hduser/table1/'
```

Answer (score 0):

Try  below code

```
CREATE TABLE TABLEname  (coll INT, coll STRING, coll INT)
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ‘,’
LOCATION ‘/user/hduser/table1/*/*’;
```

Comment: This will not work as I have files like below "/user/hduser/table1/20160912000000/file1 & /user/hduser/table1/20160912000000/file2" , "/user/hduser/table1/20160912100000/file3 & /user/hduser/table1/20160912100000/file4" and "/user/hduser/table1/20160912121000/file5 & /user/hduser/table1/20160912121000/file6". I want to read all files from file1 to file6

Comment: I have edited the answer assuming there will be file related to the same table under  /user/hduser/table1/

Comment: No, still it is still not picking up the data after using LOCATION value as you stated above.

Comment: what is the output  or what is the error ... or any extra folder there...